# ASP.Net MVC: Exporting the results of an ApiController action

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

In my application I have a few grids that each get their data source from an `ApiController` action. I want to add an option for the user to export these grid into either CSV, PDF, Excel, etc. Writing code to convert the datasource to the expected format is not problem. The problem is that I want to write re-usable code. Currently I have a separate action for each grid.

I could very easily add a new Export controller with matching actions that call into the same logic as the `ApiController`, but that means if I have five `ApiController` actions I will need five additional `Controller` actions.

What i'm wondering if if there was a way I could make a single export `Controller` action, but somehow pass the details for the `ApiController` to it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should specify Accept header in requests. Basing on specified content type in the header an appropriate converter on the server will be used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a file (FileContentResult) in ASP.NET WebAPI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi)

Comment: @Dimi I think you should flag the other question as the duplicate. This question was asked more than a year before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found:

Instead of returning `StreamContent` as the Content, I can make it work with `ByteArrayContent`.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Generate()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    // processing the stream.

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer())
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "CertificationCard.pdf"
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```