# How to return a file (FileContentResult) in ASP.NET WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In a regular MVC controller, we can output pdf with a `FileContentResult`.

```
public FileContentResult Test(TestViewModel vm)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    //... add content to the stream.

    return File(stream.GetBuffer(), "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
}
```

But how can we change it into an `ApiController`?

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test(TestViewModel vm)
{
     //...
     return Ok(pdfOutput);
}
```

---

Here is what I've tried but it doesn't seem to work.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    //...
    var content = new StreamContent(stream);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.GetBuffer().Length;
    return Ok(content);            
}
```

The returned result displayed in the browser is:

```
{"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/pdf"]},{"Key":"Content-Length","Value":["152844"]}]}
```

And there is a similar post on SO: [Returning binary file from controller in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api?rq=1)
. It talks about output an existing file. But I could not make it work with a stream.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This post helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23768883/585552

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Instead of returning `StreamContent` as the `Content`, I can make it work with `ByteArrayContent`.

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Generate()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    // processing the stream.

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "CertificationCard.pdf"
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If the top half answers your question, please only post that as an answer. The second half appears to be a different question - post a new question for that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing, got a simple question (I guess). I have a C# front end that receives the httpresponsemessage. How do I extract the streamcontent and make it available so a user can save it to disk or something (and I can get the actual file)? Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to download a self generated excel file. Using the stream.GetBuffer() always returned an corrupted excel. If instead I use stream.ToArray() the file is generated without a problem. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @AlexandrePires That is because `MemoryStream.GetBuffer()` actually returns the MemoryStream's buffer, which is usually larger than the stream's content (to make insertions efficient). `MemoryStream.ToArray()` returns the buffer truncated to the content size.

Comment: @AlexandrePires Thank you so much. This was my problem as well

Comment: Because I was returning a large file, I needed to use the stream to buffer the contents rather than read the entire file into memory up-front. I found this answer from a different post helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549889/540061

Comment: thanks @AlexandrePires that was my case also.


I edited this answer because I don't see practical reason why someone would like to get actual underlying array that can be bigger then actual data saved to MemoryStream.

Comment: Please stop doing this. This sort of abuse of MemoryStream causes, unscalable code and completely ignores the purpose of Streams. Think: why isn't everything just exposed as `byte[]` buffers instead? Your users can easily run your application out of memory.

Comment: @makhdumi What's the alternative to MemoryStream?

Comment: @IanWarburton Streams should be streamed into one another using small, typically ~4 KB, buffers. .NET conveniently provides a method for this, [Stream.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @makhdumi Unless a webpage is using chunking when rendering, all the data will be in memory anyhow.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It does appear to return the PDR as a byte array to the front end, but then when i try to open it, i get this error "Failed to load PDF document".

Comment: You should be able to use `stream.GetBuffer()` as long as you specify the actual size using the [`ByteArrayContent(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.bytearraycontent.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_ByteArrayContent__ctor_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) constructor: `new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length))`.  This will be much more memory-efficient as `ToArray()` actually copies the contents of the internal buffer.

Comment: for file stored in a path, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58188829/9746445) worked for me.

Comment: Answer is incomplete. Where is the File to download. How to extract the file from HttpResponseMessage for users to download.

Answer (score 118):

If you want to return `IHttpActionResult` you can do it like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer())
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "test.pdf"
    };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    var response = ResponseMessage(result);

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Good update to show IHttpActionResult return type. A refactor of this code would be to move call a custom IHttpActionResult such as the one listed at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23768596/why-is-my-file-not-being-returned-by-a-get-request-from-my-web-api-function

Comment: This post demonstrates a nice tidy single use implementation. In my case, the helper method listed in the above link proved more helpful

Comment: If you vote down please say why, hard to improve answers otherwise.

Comment: I think you can only use `stream.GetBuffer()` if you specify the actual size using the [`ByteArrayContent(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.bytearraycontent.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_Http_ByteArrayContent__ctor_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) constructor: `new ByteArrayContent(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, checked((int)stream.Length))`.  The internal buffer array may be longer than the actual contents so specifying the content length is necessary.

Answer (score 53):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975886/how-to-download-a-file-using-web-api-in-asp-net-mvc-4-and-jquery) question helped me.

So, try this:

Controller code:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Test()
{
    var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/test.docx");;
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
    return result;          
}
```

View Html markup (with click event and simple url):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            // httproute = "" - using this to construct proper web api links.
            window.location.href = "@Url.Action("GetFile", "Data", new { httproute = "" })";
        });
    });
</script>


<button id="btn">
    Button text
</button>

<a href=" @Url.Action("GetFile", "Data", new { httproute = "" }) ">Data</a>
```

Comment: Here you are using `FileStream` for an existing file on the server. It is a bit different from `MemoryStream`. But thanks for the input.

Comment: If you do read from a file on a web server, be sure to use the overload for FileShare.Read, otherwise you may encounter file in use exceptions.

Comment: if you replace it with memory stream it will not work?

Comment: @JeremyBell it is just a simpified example, nobody talks here about production and fail-safe version.

Comment: @aleha, no it won't work with `MemoryStream`. It feels strange. I returned `ByteArrayContent` in the end. (see my answer below) Hope some expert in SO can explain the difference.

Comment: @Blaise See below for why this code works with `FileStream` but fails with `MemoryStream`. It's basically got to do with the Stream's `Position`.

Answer (score 26):

Here is an implementation that streams the file's content out without buffering it (buffering in byte[] / MemoryStream, etc. can be a server problem if it's a big file).

```
public class FileResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    public FileResult(string filePath)
    {
        if (filePath == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(filePath));

        FilePath = filePath;
    }

    public string FilePath { get; }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(FilePath));
        var contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(FilePath));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

It can be simply used like this:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        string filePath = GetSomeValidFilePath();
        return new FileResult(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you delete the file after the download is done? Are there any hooks to be notified when the download is finished?

Comment: ok, the answer seems to be to implement an action filter attribute and remove the file in the OnActionExecuted method.

Comment: Found this post Risord's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041717/how-to-delete-file-after-download-with-asp-net-mvc. One can use this line `var fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);` instead of `File.OpenRead(FilePath)`

Answer (score 8):

I am not exactly sure which part to blame, but here's why `MemoryStream` doesn't work for you:

As you write to `MemoryStream`, it increments its `Position` property.
The constructor of `StreamContent` takes into account the stream's current `Position`. So if you write to the stream, then pass it to `StreamContent`, the response will start from the nothingness at the end of the stream.

There's two ways to properly fix this:

1. construct content, write to stream

   ```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        // ...
        // stream.Write(...);
        // ...
        return response;
    }
   ```
2. write to stream, reset position, construct content

   ```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Test()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        // ...
        // stream.Write(...);
        // ...
        stream.Position = 0;

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
        return response;
    }
   ```
3. looks a little better if you have a fresh Stream, 1) is simpler if your stream does not start at 0

Comment: This code actually does not provide any solution to the problem, as it uses the same approach that was mentioned int the question. The question already states that this does not work, and I can confirm that. return Ok(new StreamContent(stream)) returns JSON representation of StreamContent.

Comment: Updated the code. This answer actually answers the more subtle question of 'why does the simple solution work with FileStream but not MemoryStream' rather than how to return a File in WebApi.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was the difference between

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new StringContent(log, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/octet-stream");
```

and

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(log, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/octet-stream");
```

The first one was returning the JSON representation of StringContent: {"Headers":[{"Key":"Content-Type","Value":["application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8"]}]}

While the second one was returning the file proper.

It seems that Request.CreateResponse has an overload that takes a string  as the second parameter and this seems to have been what was causing the StringContent object itself to be rendered as a string, instead of the actual content.

Answer (score 5):

I found this article useful: https://codeburst.io/download-files-using-web-api-ae1d1025f0a9

Basically it says:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class JobController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetFile()
    {
        byte[] fileContent = GetFile();
        return File(fileContent, "application/pdf", "test.pdf");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is for .Net Core

Answer (score -3):

```
 var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                await cloudFile.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
                responseMessage.result = "Success";

                var contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            
                **using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {                    
                    return File(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), contentType, "Cartage.pdf");
                }**
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.