# How to return a IHttpActionResult with Http status code 200 and pass in a memory stream in the http response

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In my APIController.cs Get() method, how can I return a IHttpActionResult with HTTP status code 200 and pass in a memory stream in the HTTP response?

I tried doing this:

```
    var sr = new StreamReader(myMemoryStream);
    string myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return Ok(myStr);
```

But it converts my memory stream to string and pass that to Ok(). But I don't want to my memory stream to stream before sending in http respone.
And I don't see any method in the OkResult object which allows me to set the response stream.

How can I set the http response body?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with web api, but maybe something like this HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, sr);
    return response;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26041298/2779990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetFile()
{
  byte[] byteArray; 
  using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
     // Do you processign here
     byteArray = memoryStream.ToArray();
  }
  var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
  response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
  response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
  //suppose its .xlsx file
  response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Sample.xlsx";
  return response;
}
```

if you are returning IHttpActionResult, then return

```
 return ResponseMessage(GetFile());
```

Please let me know if you want client side code also

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetStream()
 {
    MemoryStream myMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(myMemoryStream);
    string myStr = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return Ok(myStr);          
 }
```