# issue with returning HttpResponseMessage as excel file in WebAPI

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-web-api, closedxml

I have created WebAPI which returns an excel file using closedxml nuget. Basically it converts my `DataTable` to  excel. I'm referring couple of links below,

1. [How to return a file (FileContentResult) in ASP.NET WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi)
2. [Returning binary file from controller in ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541351/returning-binary-file-from-controller-in-asp-net-web-api?rq=1)

**Issue :** excel generated on server path has NO issues. But when I download the same by returning it as `HttpResponseMessage` via webAPI the excel file is corrupted. It says, "The file is corrupt and cannot be opened" :(

[image]

**My Code :**

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public HttpResponseMessage ExportExcel()
            {                 
                     DataTable scoredRecords = Getdt();
                     if (scoredRecords.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var path = @"C:\Raghav\asdf.xlsx";
                            XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook();
                            wb.Worksheets.Add(scoredRecords, "sample");
                            // excel getting generated on server properly-No issues.
                            wb.SaveAs(path);
                            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                            var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
                            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
                            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                            {
                                FileName = "sample.xlsx"
                            };
                            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
                            //tried with "application/ms-excel" also
                            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
                            return result;
                        }

               }
```

**The generated excel on server has no issues.** Only the downloaded excel file via webAPI is corrupted. Unable to figure out the issue.. 
any help appreciated!! :)

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm experiencing the same problem. Not to mention other RFC compliance issues with firewalls not happy with the content-length being returned.

Comment: unfortunately, it was an issue with swagger UI negate package ! :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Export()
    {
        using (var wb = new XLWorkbook())
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            wb.Worksheets.Add("sample").FirstCell().SetValue("some value");

            wb.SaveAs(ms);

            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer());
            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = ms.Length;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = "sample.xlsx"
            };
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One issue I am seeing is that :

```
 var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
```

you are sending FileStream. Instead of this, you can try with `byte []` :

```
byte[] excelData  = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
result.Content = new StreamContent(excelData);
```

You can give a try with this.

Comment: result.Content = new StreamContent(excelData);

StreamContent required System.IO.Stream

Comment: Maybe: new ByteArrayContent(excelData);