# Get image via .net web api

Tags: c#, android, rest, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to build a .net web API to send images from my service to android device, unfortunately the company that i work have a system such as i cant take the images via URL, i have tried Base64 to send the images to my phone but its too slow, can anyone help me. how can i send the images from my service to android (GET API) fast.
this is a part from my API:

```
string base64String = "";
using (Image image = Image.FromFile(DALParameter.GetByCode(PATH)
{
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(m, image.RawFormat);
        byte[] imageBytes = m.ToArray();
        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by without url? Is it without extension? Anyway you have to call via a url.

Comment: @cdev the images is in my server and i cant reach them with a url from browser etc.

Comment: the only way i have is to get the images via web service but base 64 is too slow

Comment: public ActionResult GetImage()  { return File(path, "image/jpeg");// @"C:\sampleimage.jpg" }, What is the reason that you cant you use something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you loading your image with `Image.FromFile` and not send it directly? You just send image normally as file like in this answer [How to return a file (FileContentResult) in ASP.NET WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi/26040968)

Remember to use correct mime type for image instead of "application/octet-stream". For png that's "image/png" and for jpeg/jpg it's "image/jpeg"