# Which server side app should I pick for file transfare scenario

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I created some chrome extension that detects a file download event and cancel the download, and gets the download link. Sends the link to myserver.

I want to create a server that recive link to download, download the file, do some manipulation on the file and sends the file back to client.

[image]

All the time I developed client side apps (Mainly with c#), and I don't know what to choose for the server side, WCF App or Web API (or something else). the server can be inside the organisation or remote.

What do you think should I pick? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that creating Restful-style services may be more appropriate for this scenario. 
You know, both WCF and Asp.net WebAPI can create Restful-style services. WCF could take advantage of the Webhttpbinding to create it.
As for handling file uploads and downloads, I don't think there is any difference between the two techniques. Perhaps the services created by Asp.net WebAPI are a little more mature, such as the ability to deal with form-data stream (multipart/form-data) directly. While WCF service could not directly process the form-data stream.
Here is an example of an upload and download in Asp.net WebAPI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2
[How to return a file (FileContentResult) in ASP.NET WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi/26041298)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.