# ControllerBase.File missing from ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on an old ASP.NET WebApi with `.Net Framework 4.6.1` and MVC3 project. The problem is that I don't have the File return type, not the one from System.IO but the one **from the controller**.
In ASP.NET Core for example, this File is located in ControllerBase class. So, since my project only knows about `System.IO.File`, when writing the following code I get the following error:

**code:**

```
return File(memory, mimeType, document.Name);
```

**error:**

```
Provides static methods for the creation, copying, deletion, moving, and opening of a single file, and aids in the creation of a FileStream objects.
Non-invocable member 'File' cannot be used like a method.
Method, delegate or event is expected.
```

So is there any way to get this 'File' in my project?
Thank you guys!

Comment: Can you tell us how is your controller class defined?

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi what you are looking for?

Comment: @MatteoUmili, so my Controller is defined like this : 
` [WebApiAuthorize]
    public class NetworkController : BaseApiController
    {...}`

and that BaseApiController is defined like this:

 `public abstract class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {...}`

Comment: @mjwills, thank you for your answer. So yeah, as a workaround, my function has a HttpResponseMessage return type, as in the provided link.
However, I prefer going for ActionResult return type, and return a "ControllerBase.File" result. And here comes the problem, ControllerBase.File does not exist.

Comment: @FMR i'am realy sorry i have not understand what is the value that you bring to the post  by your comment .

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up your .net API's the [File() method is from .net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.1), you're using .net framework, so that's why File isn't available. For .net framework you need to use the [HttpResponseRessage for .net framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage?view=netframework-4.6.2) in your controller, something like below:

```
    byte[] msarray = memory;

    HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage();
    httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(msarray);
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", document.Name);
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = filename;
    httpResponseMessage.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    return httpResponseMessage;
```