# Problem return File(content, contentType, fileName); when im trying to export

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im trying to export an excel file with apiController in asp.net mvc
This is my code:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[HttpRoute("report/historicalExpirations/excel")]
public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult Excel([FromBody] HistoricalExpirationDto HeDto) {
  string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
  string fileName = "VencimientosHistoricos.xlsx";
  var res = _reportRepository.HistoricalExpirations(HeDto.CompanyCode, HeDto.Date, HeDto.EntityCode);

  using(var workbook = new XLWorkbook()) {
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Historico de Vencimientos");
    var currentRow = 1;

    #region Headers
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "Fecha";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = "Id";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = "Sector";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = "Proveedor";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 5).Value = "Cuit Proveedor";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).Value = "Proveedor Habilitado";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 7).Value = "Codigo Recurso";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 8).Value = "Tipo Recurso";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 9).Value = "Recurso";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 10).Value = "Recurso Habilitado";
    worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 11).Value = "Motivo";

    #endregion

    #region Body
    foreach(var reg in res) {
      currentRow++;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = reg.Date;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = reg.Id;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 3).Value = reg.Sector;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 4).Value = reg.Provider;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 5).Value = reg.CuitProvider;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 6).Value = reg.EnabledProvider;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 7).Value = reg.ResourceCode;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 8).Value = reg.ResourceType;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 9).Value = reg.Resource;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 10).Value = reg.EnabledResource;
      worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 11).Value = reg.Motive;
    }
    #endregion

    using(var stream = new MemoryStream()) {
      workbook.SaveAs(stream);
      var content = stream.ToArray();
      return File(content, contentType, fileName);
    }
  }
}
```

> Error:
> Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
> Error   CS1955  No se puede usar como método el miembro 'File' no invocable.

Comment: The File that you're using most likely belong to 'System.IO'. May be please try this.File ?

Comment: "ReportController" does not contain a definition for "File" or an accessible extension method "File

Comment: I see you are using API Controller.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a file (FileContentResult) in ASP.NET WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi)