# Download 1 Constant File - MVC asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Scenario,
I have a webpage, when a user open it they fill out a form and can download a T&C pdf file.

How to do this?

This is my controller code:

```
   public FileResult DownloadFile()
    {
       
        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"\\server\wwwroot\testapp\Files\Terms and Conditions.pdf");
        string fileName = "Terms and Conditions.pdf";
        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
    }
```

What do I do on the Index (.cshtml) page for a download link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a file (FileContentResult) in ASP.NET WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26038856/how-to-return-a-file-filecontentresult-in-asp-net-webapi)

Comment: This is the answer. Just what I wanted. Can you answer so that I can mark it? @MashedSpud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the "Terms and Conditions.pdf" file change in anyway based on the data captured when the user completes the form? If not, could you not simply use an
`<a href="https://example.com/testapp/Terms%20and%20Conditions.pdf">Terms and Conditions</a>` link?